# Jetpack Compose and Room DB: Performance overhead of auto-saving user input?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I'm writing an app with Jetpack Compose that lets the user input text in some `TextFields` and check a few radio buttons.

This data is then stored in a Room database.

Currently, I have a "save" button at the bottom of the screen, with a "Leave without saving?" popup.

However, I'd like to get rid of the save button entirely and have it autosave data as it's being typed.

Would the repeated DB queries from typing cause any performance issues? And are there any established best practices for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With kotlin flow you can use [`debounce`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html), which is designed specifically for such cases. That way, as long as the user enters text, `saveToDatabase` will not be called, and when he does not enter a character for some time (in my example it is one second) - the flow will be emitted.

Also during Compose Navigation the view model may be destroyed (and the coroutine will be cancelled) if the screen is closed, in that case I also save the data inside `onCleared` to make sure that nothing is missing.

```
class ScreenViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _text = MutableStateFlow("")
    val text: StateFlow<String> = _text

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            @OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
            _text.debounce(1000)
                .collect(::saveToDatabase)
        }
    }

    fun updateText(text: String) {
        _text.value = text
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        saveToDatabase(_text.value)
    }
    
    private fun saveToDatabase(text: String) {
        
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenView(
    viewModel: ScreenViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val text by viewModel.text.collectAsState()
    TextField(value = text, onValueChange = viewModel::updateText)
}
```

`@OptIn(FlowPreview::class)` means that the API may be changed in the future. If you don't want to use it now, see the replacement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57252799/3585796).

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I need. If I'm doing this for many fields, would it be better to have separate functions for updating each field, or should I update the whole entity at once?

Comment: @Miles I would update them one at a time, writing to the database once a second shouldn't affect performance, at least if you're doing it correctly, in background, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't `saveToDatabase` be a `suspend` function? In which case you would also need `viewModelScope.launch` and the coroutine will be cancelled even if launched from `onCleared`.

Comment: @BPDev in real life I personally use 0.3 seconds, and this time is enough, because close screen animation takes about the same time. but yes, you can launch it on a different coroutine scope, e.g. `MainScope` or on DB coroutine scope

Comment: I tried `LocalLifecycleOwner.current` and `DisposableEffect` and noticed that `Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE` is triggered when navigating to a different screen, so you could send an event from the composable to the view model and use `viewModelScope`. [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect)

Answer (score 0):

I group all the fields in a `data class` instead of having separate fields.

```
@Entity
data class Counter(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    val title: String = "",
    val count: Double = 0.0,
) // for Room
```

Then, I use a debounce of 300ms.

```
@OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
@HiltViewModel
class AddEditViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCases: CounterUseCases,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _counter = MutableStateFlow(Counter())
    val counter = _counter.asStateFlow()

    private val _uiEventFlow = MutableSharedFlow<UiEvent>()
    val uiEventFlow = _uiEventFlow.asSharedFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // find counter
            val id = savedStateHandle.get<Int>("id")
            if (id != null && id != -1) {
                useCases.getCounter(id)?.let {
                    // found
                    _counter.value = it
                }
            }

            autoSave()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun autoSave() {
        counter
            .drop(1) // avoid saving initial value
            .debounce(300) // wait until nothing changed for 300ms
            .collectLatest {// cancels previous block if it took too long to process the new/latest value
                val id = useCases.insertCounter(it)
                Log.d("SAVE", "$it $id")

                // for new counters, the id is 0, so each save will create a new counter in the database
                if (counter.value.id != id){
                    _counter.value = counter.value.copy(id = id) // will trigger another save, not sure how to avoid it

                    // change navigation argument from the default -1 to an actual id
                    savedStateHandle["id"] = id
                }
            }
    }

    fun handleEvent(event: AddEditEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is AddEditEvent.TitleChange -> {
                _counter.value = counter.value.copy(title = event.value)
            }
        }
    }

    sealed class UiEvent {
        data class ShowSnackbar(val message: String) : UiEvent()
        object GoBack : UiEvent()
    }
}
```

It is a little trickier to automatically save a new item. You might need to change the navigation arguments so that the id of the newly created item is used. With Room, to get the auto generated id, return `Long`:

```
@Dao
interface CounterDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM counter")
    fun getCounters(): Flow<List<Counter>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM counter WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getCounterById(id: Int): Counter?

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertCounter(counter: Counter): Long
}
```

If you have auto generated fields such as `createdAt` and `updatedAt`, `getCounterById` would need to return a `Flow`.

Edit:
If the user navigates back, the coroutine has an opportunity to be cancelled due to `debounce`. In `onCleared`, `viewModelScope` doesn't work so I use `GlobalScope`.

```
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        GlobalScope.launch {
            useCases.insertCounter(counter.value)
        }
    }
```