# Which techniques & APIs are necessary for live search when user is typing?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, desktop-application, kotlin-multiplatform

What components or APIs do I need to look into in order to create a live serach when the user is typing a search query? Currently I call a `search()` method that instantly queries a database and is called inside the `onValueChange`. But this obviously is laggy and prevents the user from typing quickly:

```kotlin
TextField(
    value = viewModel.filter.currencyCode,
    label = { Text("Currency") },
    onValueChange = {
        viewModel.filter.currencyCode = it
        viewModel.search() // <-- triggers the search in a database
    },
    singleLine = true,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(PaddingValues(vertical = 2.dp)).weight(2f)
)
```

Comment: If `search` takes much time, you need to sort out how to not call this method on the main thread - e.g. create a coroutine scope and launch request there. I think for a local request it should be enough, but you can also add `debounce` to wait user to stop typing before executing the query check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69690684/3585796)

Comment: @PhilDukhov oh, it's called `debounce`! That's what I was looking for, I guess.